# Data BindingGroup to Datatable using 4.5 .NET framework

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

I am trying to use binding group to validate all my fields in a datatable and have managed to find an example project to download to use to implement into my own project. MY problem was that everytime I added the code to my own code I was getting a Object reference not set to an instance of an object error in my validation result code whereas the sample project did not. I have managed to isolate it down through trial and error to the projects properties .NET setting but cannot figure out how to get passed my problem. The code below code works in .NET 3.5 but not in .NET 4.5 if anyone can figure out my problem.

thanks Callum

```
<Window x:Class="WPFTypeValidation.GroupValidation"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WPFTypeValidation"
    Title="Validation Demo" Height="130" Width="200">    

<Window.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="20"/>
        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Top"/>            
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>

<Border Padding="5">
    <Grid x:Name="RootElement" >     
        <Grid.BindingGroup>
            <BindingGroup>
                <BindingGroup.ValidationRules>
                    <local:PersonValidationRule
                        ValidationStep="UpdatedValue"/>
                </BindingGroup.ValidationRules>
            </BindingGroup>
        </Grid.BindingGroup>

        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1.8*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Label Content="Name:"/>
        <TextBox Grid.Column="1" LostFocus="TextBox_LostFocus"    
                 Text="{Binding Name, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>

        <Label Grid.Row="1" Content="Age:"/>
        <TextBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" LostFocus="TextBox_LostFocus"
                 Text="{Binding Age, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>     

        <Label Grid.Row="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Foreground="Red"
               Content="{Binding Path=(Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent, ElementName=RootElement}"/>         
    </Grid>
</Border>
```

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace WPFTypeValidation
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for Window1.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class GroupValidation : Window
    {
        private DataTable FirstMenuDT;

        public GroupValidation()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            FirstMenuDT = new DataTable();
            FirstMenuDT.Columns.Add("Name");
            FirstMenuDT.Columns.Add("Age");
            FirstMenuDT.Rows.Add("Fantastic Mr. Fish", 34);
            RootElement.DataContext = FirstMenuDT;
        }

        private void TextBox_LostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            RootElement.BindingGroup.CommitEdit();
        }       
    }

    public class PersonValidationRule : ValidationRule
    {
        public override ValidationResult Validate(object value, CultureInfo cultureInfo)
        {
            var dataRowView = (value as BindingGroup).Items[0] as DataRowView;

            string Initial;
            var statusEx = new Regex(@"^[A-Z ]+$");

            Initial = dataRowView.Row[0].ToString();

            if (Initial == string.Empty)
            {
                return new ValidationResult(false, "Initial cannot be empty.");
            }

            if (!statusEx.Match(Initial).Success)
            {
                return new ValidationResult(false,
               "Initials column must be in uppercase alphabetic characters only.");
            }

            if (Initial.Length > 3)
            {
                return new ValidationResult(false,
               "Maximum of 3 characters only.");
            }

            return new ValidationResult(true, null);
        }
    }
}
```